# Installing or giving my app system level permissions (API 30+)

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, android-source

I'm currently trying to develop a system app or a application with system level permission so it can for example change language and disable/enable wifi etc.
There are some examples out there with `sharedUserId` and starting the emulator in `-writable-system` and so on. But none of these seems to work on API 30 and above.

I managed to install my app as a system app on a emulator running API level 28.

I found the following online: Starting with Android 11, Google has implemented stricter security measures to prevent unauthorized access to the `/system` partition, including the `/system/priv-app/` directory. This means that even with root access, it may not be possible to modify the contents of the `/system/priv-app/` directory on devices running Android 11 or later.

So my question is, is building my own ROM and granting my application the system certificate the only option I have?

I have tried the following:

- installing the app in `/system/priv-app/` directory (works on API 28 and lower).
- granting `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` via ADB at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The references you are mentioning are security enhancements done by Google over time. Have you tried disabling verity?

However,the best yet time consuming bet is to actually include the app as a part of the OS build, and also sign it with the platform key. This has also changed a bit after android 11 (API Level 30).
I was able to make a quick guide explaining in detail how to achieve this.
https://hackernoon.com/modern-way-of-building-android-app-from-source-in-aosp-environment

Comment: Yes I tried that also.

I'm gonna include it in my OS build instead. Thank your for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add your app to the system build, also take a look at the
`/frameworks/base/data/etc/privapp-permissions-platform.xml` file.

You can try to add the permissions to your app directly in this xml,like this:

```
<privapp-permissions package="com.your.app.package">
        <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <permission name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
        <permission name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
        <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
</privapp-permissions>
```